# Can't figure out how to put 3 image links side by side and centered

Tags: html, css, image

I have tried using float left/right, which puts them next to each other but I want them to be evenly spaced from left to right. I tried using padding/margin tags, but they don't work either. Any help would be appreciated!

Code:

```
<div class="options">
 <ul style="list-style:none;">
 <li>
  <a href="http://www.cesarsway.com/askthevet/serioushealthadvice/Household-Items-That-Could-Harm-Your-Dog/"><img src="magger.jpg" width="180" height="180"/><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Do Stuff To His Dog</a>
  </li>
<p>
  <li>
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com/kingwoody1/"><img src="me.jpg" width="180" height="180">    <br>Examine His Checkered Past</a></p>
 </li>

<p>
 <li>
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com/jackiewoodson528/"><img src="wife.jpg" width=180 height=180><br>Sexually Harass His Wife</a></p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
 .options li {
 float:right;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're over complicating it:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="images">
    <img src="1.jpg"/>
    <img src="2.jpg"/>
    <img src="3.jpg"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.images {
    text-align : center;
}
.images img {
    width  : 75px;
    height : 75x;
    margin : 10px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6VrJR/

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css-code:

```
ul{
    width : 550px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3n6B/) as well

Answer (score 0):

**Do not use floats:**

Instead of using floats for your children elements, let them flow inside an anchor tag. Anchor tags have inline as default display behavior (add `display: inline;` if you need to use another tag instead).

The trick that centers the links is the container `text-align: center;` property.

**This can be translated in code as follows:**

**Define your container class**

```
.container {
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
}
```

**Create your HTML structure:**

```
<div class='container'>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.bradfordcityfc.co.uk/images/common/bg_player_profile_default_big.png" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.bradfordcityfc.co.uk/images/common/bg_player_profile_default_big.png" alt=""></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://www.bradfordcityfc.co.uk/images/common/bg_player_profile_default_big.png" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/manuelro/pen/Abgox

Regards,
M

Answer (score 0):

Define width and auto margin for the UL. Also, give margin and text-align center for the text.

```
.options ul {
    width:564px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:0;
}
.options li {
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 4px;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EASFG/